# Unclear questions according to the Community Bot

Tags: discussion

I arrived at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/580206/1352). When I arrived, it had been posted one minute ago, had three views, one upvote, and a single comment, posted by the Community Bot 57 seconds ago (so well within a minute after the question was posted):

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I find this automated comment a little... trigger-happy.

Can anyone shed a little light on how such auto-comments happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've reviewed the Question's history. The sequence of events is that

- a user asked their first question
- the question populates the First Question Queue
- a reviewer decided that selecting the feedback option was best
- the robot applies the comment to the post.

I think these changes were implemented as part of this project: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369148#369148)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Someone was *quick* in the review queue.